# How to hide option value using ng-if condition in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have an Input form. The two input fields that I want to compare and display values if condition true.
input fields  are :-

```
<td class="td_label"><label>Client Age :</label></td>
<td class="td_input"><input type="text" required="required" class="age" ng-model="age" name="age" maxlength="2">                          
</td>
<td class="td_label"><label>Test Age :</label></td>
<td class="td_input"><input type="number" required="required" class="libr" ng-model="libr" name="libr"  min="50" max="100">                       
</td>

<td class="td_label"><label>Rider Cost :</label></td>
<td class="td_select"><select ng-model="rider" name="rider" required>
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="0.0001">Option 1 - 3% No Rider</option>
    <option  value=".75">Option 2 - IAV 5.5% Rider .75%</option>
    <option value=".9">Option 3 - IAV 6.0% Rider .90%</option>
    <option value=".85">Option 4 - IAV 5.5% Rider .85%</option>
    <option value="1.0">Option 5 - IAV 6.0% Rider 1.0%</option>
</select></td>
```

Now, I want my 3rd option from select option will not applicable if difference test age - age is  more than 10 . what can i do ?

Comment: You can use ngOptions to bind the values to select input. Depending on the value of age - on change you could write the logic to either include or exclude an option.

Comment: @ChandrasekarG I agree with you. You might want to manage options controller side rather then applying login in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) in this case:

```
<option value=".9" ng-hide="libr && age && (libr - age > 10)">Option 3 - IAV 6.0% Rider .90%</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <option ng-disabled="age >= 10" value=".9">Option 3 - IAV 6.0% Rider .90%</option>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/8476/) is the working fiddle

Comment: not noticed your condition, but you can use `ng-disabled` with appropriate condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-hide="age - libr > 10"` to the DOM you want to hide.